# Google App Engine yaml configuration

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I have some trouble with GAE `.yaml` setting.

Here are my file path(sorry for the link, but I can't post images yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4fNb.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/moIcm.jpg

And my yaml file:

```
part 1


    application: pricecrawler-maja
    version: 1
    runtime: php55
    api_version: 1

    handlers:
    - url: /src
      static_dir: src

    - url: /vendor/moderna/
      static_dir: vendor/moderna

    - url: /vendor/twbs/
      static_dir: vendor/twbs

    - url: /404\.html
      script: /404.html
```

> Here are the php files that I don't know how to setup, 
>   so I just type like this.

```
part 2
    - url: /discount_book.php
      script: discount_book.php

    - url: /discount_book_print.php
      script: discount_book_print.php

    - url: /discount_view.php
      script: discount_view.php

    - url: /src/LIB_http.php
      script: src/LIB_http.php

    # and so on... I have typed every single php file into the yaml.

part 3

    # Serve php scripts.
    - url: /src/(.+\.php)
      script: src/\1

    - url: /(.+\.php)
      script: \1

    - url: /.*
      script: index.php
```

> And some of my php files contain code like:

```
    include_once "src/LIB_http.php";
    include_once "basic_class.php";
```

The website works fine when I run it on my pc (using wamp and GAE Launcher locally) and OpenShift.

I know that GAE yaml using regular expression to define the file direction.

The first time I deployed my project(the yaml file only contained part 1 & 2),
the website on GAE malfunctioned.
And the second time I modified app.yaml as above, the website is still malfunctioned.
I think the problem is the app.yaml.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There may be more problems, but things start to be broken at the very beginning of your `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /src
  static_dir: src
```

this means that all files in `/src` are to be served statically, *not* run in your App Engine instance -- as a consequences, the files under `/src` are not even uploaded to the same place as the rest of your app.

So of course code like `include_once "src/LIB_http.php"` in other PHP files will not work: remember, you told App Engine that `/src` is a directory for *static* files to be served, not *application* files to be run, so `src/LIB_http.php` was NOT uploaded with the rest of your app's files.

Why do you think you want static file serving from `/src`? Remove that stanza (and I'd suggest also removing all of "part 2" since the regular expressions in "part 3" should be able to do that work by themselves) and while you may have other bugs (I can't debug your app from here:-) at least this major, glaring one will go away.